# Create column with values based on join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, unpivot

I have two tables **1) a customer table 2)Account table.** I want to see what accounts are primary and which are secondary accounts.

In one table I have `accountRowId`. In the other table I have `PrimaryAccountRowId` and `SecondaryAccountRowId` and ‘AccountNumber’.

For my output I would like to have all `AccountNumbers` in one column with all the ***AccountRelationship(primary or seconday)*** in another column beside each `AccountNumber`.

In order to join table, for `PrimaryAccounts` I would join `AccountRowId` on `PrimaryAccountRowId` and for secondary Accounts I would just flip flop and instead of having the `primaryAccountRowId` it would be `SecondaryAccountRowId`.

**My Account table:**

```
  AccountRowId = 256073
  AccountRowId = 342300
```

**Customer table:**

```
   PrimaryAccountRowId = 256073
   SecondaryAccountRowId = 342300
   AccountNumber = 8003564
  AccountNumber = 2034666
```

What I want to see my table look like

```
     AccoundNumber        AccountRelationship
      8003564             Primary
      2034666             Secondary
```

Please provide some helpful logic/code of how I would achieve these results.

From the OP's comments here is the table structure.

```
Create table Customer
(
    AccountNumber Varchar(50)
    , PrimaryAccountRowId Varchar(15)
    , SecondaryAccountRowId Varchar(15)
); 

Create table Account
( 
    AccountRowId Varchar(15)
);
```

Comment: I think you need to provide the table structure. You do NOT have two columns names AccountNumber in your customer table.

Comment: @SeanLange I have one AccountNumber column I was just saying what I have in my table I have two accountNumber values and two different accountrowid values

Comment: So share the structure of your tables. This isn't going to be difficult to query but without the table definition this is just guesswork.

Comment: How does a column have 2 values? A column only has 1 value, not 2.

Comment: @Larnu one for each record please see the information I provided

Comment: The information you provided says that your table `Customer` has 2 columns called `AccountNumber`, which is impossible, as @SeanLange tells you. You followed that up with *"in my table I have two accountNumber values and two different accountrowid values"* which I read to mean you're saying that storing multiple values in a single column (which you also can't do).

Comment: Can you provide the table structure of your `Customer` table?

Comment: Why should you provide the table structure and sample data for what seems so simple? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query You would have an answer already if we knew what we were working with.

Comment: Create table Customer(
AccountNumber Varchar(50),
PrimaryAccountRowId Varchar(15),
SecondaryAccountRowId Varchar(15));

Create table Account(
AccountRowId Varchar(15));

Comment: You really should add those kinds of details to the question as it is relevant to the question. Plus comment formatting is horrific.

Answer (score 0):

I am still somewhat guessing here. You need to provide table structure, sample data and desired output to make it easy for people to help you. Something along these lines.

```
declare @Customer table
(
    AccountNumber Varchar(50)
    , PrimaryAccountRowId Varchar(15)
    , SecondaryAccountRowId Varchar(15)
)

insert @Customer values
('8003564', '256073', null)
, ('2034666', null, '342300')

declare @Account table
(
    AccountRowid Varchar(15)
)

INSERT @Account values
('256073'), ('342300')
```

Now that we have some tables and data to work with this just becomes a case of conditional aggregation. This should return the data you are looking for as I understand the need.

```
select c.AccountNumber
    , AccountRelationship = max(case when p.AccountRowId is not null then 'Primary' when c.SecondaryAccountRowId is not null then 'Secondary' end)
from @Customer c
left join @Account p on p.AccountRowid = c.PrimaryAccountRowId
left join @Account s on s.AccountRowid = c.SecondaryAccountRowId
group by c.AccountNumber
order by AccountRelationship
```